# Jquery Array Wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending an AJAX request and for the error response, it comes back as an array since I'm sending an array to my controller. Here's how it's being sent.

```
var data = { 'typeDetails[games]' : [], 'typeDetails[art]' : [] };
```

The error data is coming back as

```
typeDetails.games.0 {
    0: 'this is text',
},
typeDetails.art.0 {
    0: 'this is more text',
}
```

I can parse this by using the following.

```
var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
console.log(errors["typeDetails.games.0"]);
```

However, instead of "games", I need a wildcard in there in case it's "art". I've tried an *, but not working. My searching has only come up with other methods to figure out what that middle string should be if it's not "games". Does a wildcard exist as an easy replacement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `for..in` loop to iterate properties, values of object

```
var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

for (var err in errors) {
  // do stuff with property `err` in object `errors`
  console.log(err,  errors[err])
}
```